# Mailgun API rejecting messages for unknown reason

Tags: html, email, mailgun

I ran a small test (three messages) of sending HTML email.  All three rejected (400) with the following:

```
{https://api.mailgun.net:443 "POST /v3/mg001.[mydomain].com/messages.mime HTTP/1.1" 400 0}
```

I literally have no idea what it's telling me.

The python code that "sends" the email is:

```
def send_message(sender, subject, body_text, body_html, recipient):
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg001.[mydomain].com/messages.mime",
        auth=("api", "[myapikey]"),
        data={"from": sender,
              "to": recipient,
              "subject": subject,
              "text": body_text,
              "html": body_html},
        headers={"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
        )
```

I have slightly different code that sends non-html email perfectly, so I know there's nothing wrong in my account or API key, etc.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs say](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending):

> `POST /<domain>/messages.mime`
>
> Posts a message in MIME format. Note: you will need to build a MIME string yourself. Use a MIME library for your programming language to do this. Pass the resulting MIME string as message parameter.

AFAICT you are not building a MIME string, so you shouldn't be using that endpoint.  [The quickstart](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-with-smtp-or-api) shows the standard endpoint to use:

```
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages
```

[The examples in of the docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#examples) show a pretty clear example of sending an HTML message (it includes file attachments, I've removed those):

```
send_complex_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
        auth=("api", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
              "to": "foo@example.com",
              "cc": "baz@example.com",
              "bcc": "bar@example.com",
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!",
              "html": "<html>HTML version of the body</html>"})
```

None of the referenced examples includes using a `Content-Type` header either, it doesn't look like that is required.

TL;DR - when in doubt, check the docs! :-)

Comment: Thank you, SO much!  I've eliminated the attempt at sending MIME messages and returned to using the "...messages" API endpoint.  To be sure, it was "reading the docs"  when my initial attempts to send HTML mail failed, that sent me down the MIME path.  I've been a professional programmer for 40+ years and if there's any constant in our business it's that if you really have no clue what you're doing (my knowledge of email and associated constructions and protocols is as close to nil as any human being's could be) "the docs" may as easily send you down the wrong road, as the right!

Comment: BTW, I haven't actually received my test html email at my inbox, but I got "200" returns from the API, so I assume they're in the queue.